# How to modify inline JS before execution/page load in Chrome/FF?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I'm trying to work on a page whose source I don't have access to - the dev's on that side accidentally updated a piece of functionality to point to the wrong domain...

I just want to continue development, but would need something that will let me do this before the script has a chance to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this answer interesting:

[Intercept and use local files in http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821224/intercept-and-use-local-files-in-http-requests)

It basically proposes using Fiddler to server all the files from the live site except the ones that you choose (that you can use to load from your disk) and you may continue developing with your version of the site without affecting the actual environment.

**EDIT:** You actually don't *need* to use Fiddler, since most proxies thought for development will have some feature that enables you to answer with your own responses to certain requests. Fiddler does have, however, an in built feature for that, and in that answer some others (like Charle's proxy) are shown as alternatives with similar features.

Comment: Thanks Alpha!  Trying it out now..  Looks promising.

Comment: So I gave this a shot and at first it appeared to be working... but the source modifications I made to the page I'm trying to inject are not there... hrm...

Comment: If you're making changes into the exact same file, make sure that the proxy is serving the same file that you're modifying.

Comment: Actually I just noticed... the "file" itself doesn't exactly show in the list - I am beginning to wonder if this is a futile attempt due to the fact that the file I'm trying to replace is over https... ?

Comment: @user446936 That should not be a problem, Fiddler can decrypt HTTPS requests as well. Check [this link](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS).

Comment: Thank you very much Alpha.  You are 100% right.  I've finally decrypted the traffic (although the instructions for making domain-specific decryption rules in fiddlerscript is a lie).  In my particular case the response was also compressed - this was easy to handle - simply right click the response and choose "Decode Selected Sessions" at the top of the menu.

Thanks again Alpha.  You're a life saver.

Comment: @user446936 I'm glad to help! Just paying it forward, it's filled with life saver people around here and they've certainly saved me as well. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately a couple of hours later... it randomly decides to stop working.  Grrrr!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Feel free to bring up another question about the specific issue you're having.

Comment: I figured it out - it was unrelated.