# Fiddler - Replace file requested by local one

Tags: file-upload, fiddler, reverse

Is is possible to add a rule to Fiddler so that it uses a local file instead of the online version?
There's a GET to /something/somefile.swf that is always made, but I need to use mylocalversion.swf 
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24774508/10245 shows how to use AutoResponders to do this for full hosts, this also works for serving from the filesyetem.

Comment: Detailed howto: https://ohadsc.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/mapping-network-resources-to-local-files-using-fiddler/

Comment: More fiddler docs on the AutoResponder: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/generate-traffic/tasks/modifyautoresponder

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can absolutely use FiddlerScript for this, but the task you're describing is exactly what the **AutoResponder** feature was designed for.

Learn more here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DWqYXKarA and here: 
http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/AutoResponder

Comment: How would you achieve this using FiddlerScript?
The AutoResponder works fine in most cases, but in my case I need to mock an entire folder where file names have spaces, so even a regex backreference is not sufficient because instances of "%20" need to be replaced by " ". Seems like FiddlerScript only accept http, https, or ftp; hence my question on how you could use FiddlerScript to return a local file (without a local server).

Comment: Set the `x-replywithfile` flag on the Session; see https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse