# How to caching javascript in ssl using firefox?

Tags: javascript, ssl, caching, https

i caching for saving bandwidth because that site a lot access by me and the js scripts quite big and my speed internet connection is low and i cannot afford high end connection.
if i block 1 of the js then the website will be error or some function not working.
i have try tamper data , response header editor , redirector to localhost (firefox addon) but it seem all fail , also i have tried squid
remember the js is from ssl / https connection
i use window xp and firefox 45 esr
anyone have solution ?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https)?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand and may be a duplicate.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes that question just answer from server side perspective that server can change header easily  .. i ask question from client side perspective

Comment: @TomAranda yes it is very difficult question , i have try a lot  of addon firefox and it seem fail

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so although there is no clear question here, I can understand the goal you are trying to accomplish. What you are looking for is called a "proxy" or "tunnel" with in-built cachement support.

As for attempting to bypass js loading, Images are ALWAYS going to be the most "costliest" "transaction".

Bypassing these transactions are not what most browsers attempt to do, although omitting JS can be a "security benefit" in certain circumstance so it was added to most browsers.

In summary, it is rather easy to disable js but will always have the side-effects you describe and in the modern internet, it is actually a disability because most systems rely on javascript.

Comment: yes yes website use a lot javascript and some website use a lot of size and we have to downloaded same js and js again and again (same js) and i think website maker like that is not profesional

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want to retrieve the js script from your local machine to save some internet bandwidth. If this is the case, then you can use Fiddler AutoResponder rules to achieve your goal.

Learn more here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3DWqYXKarA  and here: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/AutoResponder

NOTE: This has already been answered by @EricLaw in [Fiddler - Replace file requested by local one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033990/fiddler-replace-file-requested-by-local-one)

And also answered by @epascarello in [How to replace Javascript of production website with local Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936490/how-to-replace-javascript-of-production-website-with-local-javascript)

Comment: yes it is good ..  thank you  ..  but with firefox portable , it do not work  ... do you know why this happen ???

Comment: You may need to follow the instructions from the following link, to get Fiddler configured with your firefox.
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler